# Если в уточнении два союза "и", разделённые запятой, она явно лишняя?

Tags: пунктуация, уточнения

Или не явно...

> Мы видим, как идеи и ценности отдельно взятой эпохи, и философские, и
>   художественные, существовали и передавались на протяжении поколений.

Потонем в запятых?

*Мы видим, как идеи и ценности отдельно взятой эпохи - и философские, и художественные - существовали и передавались на протяжении поколений.*

Так?

А с протяжением поколений все ли стилистически верно?

Comment: Оба "и" можно уложить между двумя тире или в скобки; с поколениями терпимо: есть даже такая мера времени (лет 35).

Comment: Наверно, и правда, терпимо; по крайней мере, в Нацкорпусе пять примеров на "протяжении поколений" (в этом падеже).

Comment: Тёмыч, меня смутило *идеи и ценности... передавались на протяжении поколений* - кому передавались на протяжении?

Comment: Наверно, от одного поколения к другому?

Comment: Да, нет явного упоминания, кому или куда передавались - будто тайной организации.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Запятые лучше оставить, они смотрятся нормально, вставочная интонация будет читаться хуже.

2) Как вариант: Мы видим, как идеи и ценности отдельно взятой эпохи, и философские, и художественные, () существовали  и передавались **от поколения к поколению.**

Примечание. Ещё бы добавить какое-нибудь слово на месте скобок, а то нет "равновесия", например: действительно существовали.

Пример: Язык передаётся от поколения к поколению через устное общение. [А. А. Зализняк. Лингвистика по А. Т. Фоменко // «Вопросы языкознания», 2000]